# Rails - Devise lag when sending welcome email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I send a welcome email to a user after he was create using the following code in my model:

```
after_create :send_welcome_email
...

def send_welcome_email
  EmailerUtilizator.welcome_email(self).deliver
end
```

I do this with an ajax call, the delived method has a short but noticeable delay.
Shall I use an async method ? 
Or shall I use some sort of waiting animation ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps combine with [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)? If they receive an email in 2-3 minutes even it's acceptable and also consider the scenario of concurrent registrations!

```
def send_welcome_email
  EmailerUtilizator.delay.welcome_email(self)
end
```

Comment: Consider Resque (Redis backed) which is far more scalable; delayed_job may stress your DB if the number of jobs start to scale up.